# Blocked from editing due to an edit needing review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

There is a question posed that I would like to edit (mainly the issue is that it was a new user, and so an image showing the output of a plotting command could not be put directly in and I'd like to add it).

The question was edited by someone, and I felt that the edit was not an improvement and I rejected it.

However, now when I click on 'edit' to make the changes, I cannot.  Instead it shows me the proposed edit that still needs review by others.

Any advice?  Can this "feature" be prevented in the future?

Comment: The functionality surrounding pending edits was changed not that long ago. It used to be possible to force an edit, as the second section of the linked duplicate says. However, that is no longer possible. I've updated my answer on the duplicate question to indicate that editing the post is not possible when you've already reviewed the suggested edit and the suggested edit is still pending.

Comment: It might still be possible using the mobile API/the old SE apps